# Split a string with any of the words in an array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Suppose I have a string like this:

> Ch #RoKamb93 ajesop de Bourg #kin #kinnl 9 kunsho
>   taffetas,bunughs rges, note florale,parfaite aseref

My array of delimiters can be :

```
array('#kin', '#kinnl', '#xxx' );
```

How can Iparse it to get the **Ch #RoKamb93 ajesop de Bourg** substring ? Substring just before **#kin** OR **#kinnl**

Note: Both **#kin** OR **#kinnl** may not present at the same time.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the rules by which you want to parse the string? Also ... http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$string = 'Ch #RoKamb93 ajesop de Bourg #kin #kinnl 9 kunsho taffetas,bunughs rges, note florale,parfaite aseref';

$delimiters = array('#kin', '#kinnl', '#xxx');
$pattern = '/' . implode($delimiters, '|') . '/';

$split = preg_split($pattern, $string);
var_dump($split); // $split[0] has what you need
```

If your delimiters contain reserved regex characters (like `.` or `?`), you'll need to do something like this for the pattern:

```
$pattern = '/' . implode(array_map('preg_quote', $delimiters), '|') . '/';
```